# Accessing current instance model attributes for a static function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two Models: `User & API`, In my API model I have a static function

```
  # Register account associated characters
  public
  def self.register_characters(apiid, vcode, userid)

    # Fetch XML
    api = EAAL::API.new("#{apiid}", "#{vcode}", "account")
    result = api.Characters

    # Pull characters
    result.characters.each do |char|

      if Character.find_by_charid(char.characterID.to_i).nil?

        character = Character.new(
          :charid  =>  char.characterID.to_i,
          :user_id =>  userid,
          :name    =>  char.name,
          :corp    =>  char.corporationName
        )

        character.save

        api = Api.new(
          :user_id      =>  userid,
          :character_id =>  character.id,
          :apiid        =>  apiid,
          :vcode        =>  vcode
        )
        api.save

        character.update_character
      end
    end

  end
```

I need to call this method in my `User` model on an `after_create` filter. However anyway I try to pass variables from `User` to `API` I get an error  that register_characters method is not getting `apiid or vcode` and this is when I start my rails server.

In my User model I call: `after_create Api::register_characters(:apiid, :vcode, :id)` where `:apiid`, `:vcode` and `:id` are User model properties.

**However:** Since this error appears when I try to boot my `rails server` I'm assuming that method `self.register_characters` in API is called on it self without being invoked from User model.

Anyhow how do I work around this ? Should I just make it a standard method or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the flow more readable, I suggest you define a new method for calling the method you want.

```
after_create :register_characters_on_the_api

private

def register_characters_on_the_api
  Api.register_characters(apiid, vcode, id)
end
```

You also need to remove the colons before the parameters so it will use the attributes of the instance.  Passing `:apiid`, for instance, just passes a symbol and not the apiid of the instance.